# Create new, named instance of SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, deployment, command-line, bootstrapping

Either through bootstrapper or command line install, I need to be able to create a new named instance of SQL Server. I have tried running a command line install in C#, specifying the name of the instance to be installed, and I've tried modifying the package.xml file, updating the params to reflect the new instance.  All of this to no luck at all.

I am using [RobinDotNet's 2008 R2 bootstrapper](http://robindotnet.wordpress.com/2011/02/06/how-about-a-bootstrapper-package-for-sqlserver-express-2008-r2/) to try to do the install.  I know named instances are possible through the GUI but I can't seem to get it to work in code or through bootstrapper.

Is this even possible?  Am I missing some magical parameter in the command line?  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What it came down to was two things:

1. SqlExpressChk.exe packaged with the bootstrapper did not acknowledge the fact that the instance I was trying to install was different than that of the existing instance. Therefore, the install was being skipped.
2. When using the command line, I had accidentally put spaces around the '=' for one of my params. I figured out I had an issue with my command line by letting the GUI run. Running the install in /q or /qs mode did not produce an exit code or an error. A stupid mistake on my part, but one that took a while to track down.

After fixing my command line args, everything worked as it was supposed to.

Comment: and how did you do it? I have the same issue, with clickOnce.. how can I only create a new instance if the sql server is already installed?

Comment: It's been such a long time, but if I remember correctly, I had to dive into the registry and check for the particular instance I was installing. I don't know if SqlExpressChk.exe has been improved or not since I was installing SQL Server 2012 at the time. You can use express chk to see if its installed and then check the registry...or you can just check the registry straight away. Check this link: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/askjay/archive/2011/10/11/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-installed-sql-server-instances.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You're not very clear about when exactly you are installing SQL Server. Are you using it as a prerequisite for an installer, are you installing it from an application or you just want to run a command (for example from a BAT)?

Command line installation of SQL Server 2008 R2 can be done in 2 ways:

1. By using [command line arguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144259.aspx?ppud=4)
2. By using a [configuration file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd239405.aspx)

If you are using it as a prerequisite, simply modify package.xml to include the arguments you want. You can look at the "SqlExpress" package.xml for an example.

Otherwise, simply use command line arguments or a configuration file in the SQL Server installer command line.